# Generate a plaintext file from list of words on a webpage

Tags: java, web-crawler

I am trying to generate a plain text file containing a list of words that is on a webpage. The problem is that the list is divided into multiple pages.

http://www.whonamedit.com/eponyms/A/?start=50&maxrows=25

This is what I mean. Like for the letter A, I need all 13 pages of words and I also need every letter of the alphabet.

I was thinking of maybe modifying a webcrawler to do this task, would that be the easiest way?

I prefer Java, but Python is ok.

Sorry if the answer is obvious, but any nudges in the right direction would be SO GREATLY appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is specifically for the whonamedit website, you can do the following:

```
List<String>getWordsOnPage(String url) {
  // read words within <ul class="result-list"> element.
}

void getAllWords() {
  List<String> all = new ArrayList<String>();
  for (char letter = 'A'; letter <= 'Z'; ++letter) {
    for (int start = 0; true; start += 25) {
      List<String> page = getWordsOnPage("http://www.whonamedit.com/eponyms/" + letter + "/?start=" + start + "&maxrows=25");
      if (page.isEmpty()) {
        break;
      }
      all.addAll(page);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure helping someone scrape copyrighted data is a "good thing."

Comment: @Rob -- sigh. I wasn't even thinking about that. I will be more careful in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I use [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) to write spiders